# Special Character(Unicode character ) in i/p file, R v 3.2.0. considers it as End of file

Tags: r, unicode, special-characters

I have csv file that contains special character in UTF-8 with BOM. Issue here is while reading the file in R it considers "special character" as end of file and file in not read completely.

Have attached the screen shot of special character line.

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

[Attached image containing special character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRFqF.png)

Comment: It would be great if you could supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. That way others can also befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  You can have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a great reproducible example in R.

Comment: Actually the problem in i can't even re produce an example of this particular scenario as , issue lies in csv file, and read.csv("file.name",stringsAsFactors=F) does not give any error, its just that it does not import the entire file. Apart from that the character which i have attached in screen shot "one with arrow" you can't even copy paste that character. I am not very sure how i can re produce it.

Comment: I am not sure if stackoverflow allow us to attach file. If its there i can attach csv. I am using my R on windows system

Comment: If you can't even copy that character, chances are that it's not UTF-8 and that R simply aborts reading due to the faulty encoding. The arrow doesn't look odd though, it's a normal character.